# Rails 3: write almost the same exact code 15 times in a row?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby-on-rails-3, loops, foreach

I have to write the following piece of code 15 times with the only change being the number (1 to 15) in the attribute name.

```
<% unless @post.poll.answer_1.blank? %>
  <tr>
    <td class="answer">
     <b><%= @post.poll.answer_1 %></b> - <%= pluralize(@post.poll.answer_1_votes_count, "stem", "stemmen") %>
   </td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

What is the best DRY way to do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have to use `send` method of Object class :

```
<% (1..15).each do |num| %>
 <% unless @post.poll.send("answer_#{num}").blank? %>
   <tr>
     <td class="answer">
      <b><%= @post.poll.send("answer_#{num}") %></b> - <%= pluralize(@post.poll.send("answer_#{num}_votes_count"), "stem", "stemmen") %>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thnx Amit. That works like a charm! Never seen the send method before.